# g++ template parameter error

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have GetContainer() function as follows.

```
template<typename I,typename T,typename Container>
Container& ObjCollection<I,T,Container>::GetContainer()
{
    return mContainer;
}
```

When I use this method as follows

```
template<typename I,typename T>
T& DynamicObjCollection<I,T>::Insert(T& t)
{
    GetContainer().insert(&t);
    return t;
}
```

I got errors.

```
error: there are no arguments to ‘GetContainer’ that depend on a template parameter, 
so a declaration of ‘GetContainer’ must be available

error: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of 
an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

It works fine with MSVC, but g++ is not so permissive. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you post a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I noticed that the `GetContainer` function is a method of `ObjCollection`, while `Insert` is a member of `DynamicObjectCollection`.  From this, I'm going to assume that `DynamicObjectCollection` inherits from `ObjectCollection`.

If this is indeed the case, the problem is that when you write a template class that inherits from a template base class, the way that name lookup works is slightly different from name lookup in normal classes.  In particular, you cannot just reference base class members using their names; you need to indicate to the compiler where to look for the name.  The reason this works in Visual Studio is that the Microsoft C++ compiler actually gets this behavior wrong and allows code that is technically illegal to compile just fine.

If you want to invoke the `GetContainer` function of the base class, you have two options.  First, you can explicitly indicate that the call is to a member function:

```
this->GetContainer().insert(&t);
```

Now that the compiler knows that `GetContainer` is a member of `DynamicObjectCollection`, it knows that it might need to look up `GetContainer` in the base class, and so it will defer name lookup until the template is instantiated.

The other option available would be to add a `using` declaration into the class body:

```
template <typename I, typename T>
class DynamicObjectCollection: public ObjectCollection<I, T, /* ? */> {
public:
    using ObjectCollection<I, T, /* ? */>::GetContainer;

    /* ... */
};
```

This also indicates unambiguously to the compiler that `GetContainer` may be defined in the base class, and so it defers lookup until template instantiation.

If this isn't applicable to your situation, let me know and I can delete this post.

Hope this helps!