# Unqualified access to member of dependent base class results in "A declaration of [x] must be available"

Tags: c++, templates, stack

Code:

```
// test3.cpp

#include <stack>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct ptr_stack_tp;

template<typename T>
struct ptr_stack_tp<T*> : public stack<T*>
{
    ~ptr_stack_tp()
    {
        while (!empty()) {
            operator delete(top());
            pop();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{}
```

Error message (gcc 4.7.2):

```
test3.cpp: In destructor 'ptr_stack_tp<T*>::~ptr_stack_tp()':
test3.cpp:15:23: error: there are no arguments to 'empty' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'empty' must be available [-fpermissive]
test3.cpp:15:23: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
test3.cpp:16:33: error: there are no arguments to 'top' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'top' must be available [-fpermissive]
test3.cpp:17:17: error: there are no arguments to 'pop' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'pop' must be available [-fpermissive]
```

Functions `empty()`, `top()` and `pop()` are functions of `std::stack`, so, why gcc doesn't find them?

Comment: It's a dependent name, `this->empty()` etc.

Comment: This code is risky. If you pass around a `ptr_stack_tp` as a pointer to `stack<T*>` and call `delete` on that you will get a (possibly) huge memory leak that is very difficult to find. Don't derive from standard library classes, instead implement their behaviour by composition.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should explicitly invoke base class member functions in a class template through the `this` pointer.

```
// ...

template<typename T>
struct ptr_stack_tp<T*> : public stack<T*>
{
    ~ptr_stack_tp()
    {
        while (!this->empty()) {
        //      ^^^^^^
            operator delete(this->top());
            //              ^^^^^^
            this->pop();
        //  ^^^^^^
        }
    }
};

// ...
```

This is due to the way the two-phase name lookup works for templates. Without the `this->` indirection, the compiler will look try to resolve *unqualified* names as names of global functions. Since no global functions named `empty()`, `top()`, and `pop()` exist, the compiler will emit an error.

When you are using `this->`, the compiler will delay the name lookup to the moment when the template is actually instantiated: at that point, the function calls to members of the base class will be correctly resolved.

Comment: Pretty simple indeed. Thanks.

Comment: For more information have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286922/g-template-parameter-error) as well (your question is a duplicate).

Comment: @Peregring-lk: You're welcome. Does this answer solve your problem?